# Where do I put display logic (rather than the controller)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, switch-statement, case, helper

I need to display different text based on the number of comments, and I've placed the logic in the controller. But having a long method in the controller doesn't seem very DRY, where should I put it instead?

example_controller.rb:

```
def index
  .
  count_dependent_message
  .
end

def count_dependent_message
  case @user.comment.count
        when 0
          @strong = "example Strong 0"
          @paragraph = "example paragraph 0"
        when 1
          @strong = "Jon Smith is called Smith"
          @paragraph = "example paragraph 1"
        when 2...10
          @strong = "Once upon a time...Steve Jobs... "
          @paragraph = "example paragraph 2"
        when 11...40
          @strong = "Wow you have many counts"
          @paragraph = "example paragraph 3"

        else
          @strong = "exciting"
          @paragraph = "example paragraph 4"  
  end
end
```

view:

```
<h3>
 <strong>
  <%= @strong %>
 </strong>
</h3>
<p>
<%= @paragraph %>
</p>
```

I've thought about putting the logic in a partial, but that doesn't seem very efficient since the text I want to render is just a sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the translation methods to a view helper.

```
def strong(comment_count)
   case ...
end
```

Then your view will look like:

```
<%= strong(@comment_count) %>
```

And your controller will look like:

```
@comment_count = @user.comments.count
```

This is nice because the controller won't have any display logic and the view will also be short.

Comment: Thank you Fiona! Not only did this provide the answer I was looking for, but you also showed me how to use the helper! This does seem a lot better now! Thank you. Enjoy your life!

Answer (score 0):

Move the view code to partial
eg _heading.html.erb

```
<h3>
 <strong><%= texts[:heading] %></strong>
</h3>
<p><%= texts[:text] %></p>
```

And count_dependent_message method should be

```
    def count_dependent_message(count = nil)
      case count
      when 0
        { :heading => "example Strong 0", :text => "example paragraph 0" }
      when 1
        { :heading => "Jon Smith is called Smith", :text => "example paragraph 1" }
      when 2...10
        { :heading => "Once upon a time...Steve Jobs... ", :text => "example paragraph 2" }
      when 11...40
        { :heading => "Wow you have many counts", :text => "example paragraph 3" }
      else
        { :heading => "exciting", :text => "example paragraph 4" }
      end
    end
```

Thus you can call

```
<%= render 'heading', :locals => { :texts => count_dependent_message(@user.comment.count) } %>
```

Comment: Hi Andrey, thanks for your Answer. It seems a good way, but I am not yet comfortable with symbols. But your answer has showed me clearly how to use them. thank you!!!